# redirect with html or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I am working on a page where I need to redirect people from my home page to my cover page. While still being able to go back to the home page afterwards (part of a school project) I have the link to go back to my index.html, but not sure what is best practice to redirect?

I am using the code:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=http://www.cameronwebsites.com/wps/cover.html/" />
<title>Brillings Fittings Inc - Home</title>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location.href = "http://www.cameronwebsites.com/wps/cover.html"
        </script>
</head>
```

Yet it keeps redirecting me to examples.com not the actual URL? I am very confused.

Comment: Clear the cache of your browser, that could be the issue. Ctrl+F5 should do the job

Comment: You probably don't need both the javascript, and meta redirect. Use one or the other

Comment: You should use the JavaScript redirect as the W3C discourage the use of meta refresh.

Comment: @Script47 where did you get this?

Comment: @MaximZhukov Albeit quite a long time ago, a quick search based on where I remember reading this leads [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh#Usability) which references [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-CORE-TECHS/#auto-page-refresh).

Comment: @Script47 Ok, it makes sense. Thank you for such a quick reply, appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect after X seconds, so you could show a message before go to another page

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Brillings Fittings Inc - Home</title>
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function redir(){
            window.location.href = "http://www.cameronwebsites.com/wps/cover.html"
        }
        setTimeout ("redir()", 1000); //1 second
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: I'm glad to help @JasonCameron

Answer (score 1):

If that is your actual code you are missing quotes

url should be `url="http://www.cameronwebsites.com/wps/cover.html/"`

The meta refresh tag is the simplest way to redirect so I would say you are good to go.

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='http://www.cameronwebsites.com/wps/cover.html/'" />` Single quotes should be around the url.